# CakePHP Ajax Method Not Retrieving Session Data

Tags: jquery, session, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am using CakePHP 2.3.7.

I have a method called via ajax in my controller that is not successfully retrieving the data out of the session.  I am doing the following.

I have an address form that is injected into the DOM from an ajax call.  The user submits the form with invalid data.  I get the errors and values out of the Address model and request data and write to the Session as follows:

```
public function index() {
    //On form validation fail
    $errors = $this->Address->validationErrors; 
    $data = $this->request->data;
    $this->Session->write('Address', array('errors' => $errors,
                           'data' => $data));
}
```

Do a sanity check to make sure it's in the session:

```
var_dump($this->Session->read('Address'));
```

The page now reloads and JS fires this ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/orders/getAddress.html',
    data: {"country" : country, "shipping" : shippingOption},
    dataType: 'html',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        //data is the address form html
    }
});
```

getAddress in Controller:

```
public function getAddress()
{
if($this->request->is('ajax')){
        //Gather up data to create html form and put into an array
        $data = array('states' => $states, etc...);

        //Check for errors and values in session
        if($this->Session->check('Address') == true){
             $data['errors'] = $this->Session->read('Address.errors');
             $data['values'] = $this->Session->read('Address.data');
        }
    $this->set(compact('data'));
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    }

}
```

In most cases when getAddress() fires via ajax, the form renders, but the Session is empty and my errors and values are no longer available.  It has gotten a bit maddening because it is not consistently repeatable.  Some times my data makes it to the view, sometimes it does not.  I've played around with my Session settings a bit, here is what they look like:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
'defaults' => 'database',
    'checkAgent' => false,
    'ini', array('session.cookie_secure' => false, 'session.referer_check' => false)
));
```

I added the param

```
'session.cookie_httponly' => false
```

And had a little success in my development environment, but on production, the data is still lost in the Session on the ajax call.

I'm at the end of my rope!  Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, it was an issue elsewhere in my code.  I have another ajax request that computes and returns the amount of shipping on the order to the DOM.  Within that method, I was deleting my Address session so the form wouldn't have any lingering data.  That might have been a good idea for the person first reaching the form, but it was also happening when the form reloaded after invalid data.  Although my issue was unique to my situation, hopefully my code above will assist others.